# React-Redux mapStateToProps is not being called everywhere

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am working on flash messages inside react

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(state.flashMessages);             <---This
  return {
    messages: state.flashMessages
  };
};
export class FlashMessagesComponent extends Component {
   render(){
     return <h1>Flash</h1>
   }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(FlashMessagesComponent);
```

consider  FlashMessagesComponent as the component for flash messaging   being called in People

```
http://localhost:3000/people              <--works here

import React from 'react';
const People = () =>{
    return (
        <div>
            <FlashMessagesComponent/>
            <h1>People Page</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PeopleDashboard ;
```

> The pointed line logs state of flashMessages

but

```
http://localhost:3000/basic          <--not here

const BasicPage = () =>{
    return (
        <div>
            <FlashMessagesComponent/>
            <h1>Basic Page</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default  BasicPage;
```

> the pointed line does not log i.e mapStateToProp is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause you export `FlashMessageComponent` not `connected FlashMessageComponent`.

Change

```
export class FlashMessagesComponent extends Component {
   render(){
     return <h1>Flash</h1>
   }
}
connect(mapStateToProps)(FlashMessagesComponent);
```

to

```
class FlashMessagesComponent extends Component {
   render(){
     return <h1>Flash</h1>
   }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(FlashMessagesComponent);
```

Comment: thanks some progress but it is showing 
'../../../app/common/FlashMessagesComponent' does not contain an export named
'FlashMessagesComponent'.

Comment: change `import { FlashMessagesComponent } ` to `import FlashMessagesComponent  from ...` .Cause new code is `export default` instead of export with name